# \titlespacing causes Overfull \hbox

Tags: titlesec, warnings

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}[2.5in]
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
\end{document}
```

I'm just trying to make my section titles narrower. Now I'm getting:

```
Overfull \hbox (5.1815pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--5
\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 sit amet, con-secte-tur
```

And the document looks correct. How to get rid of this warning?

Comment: although there's not enough information here to be definitive, i suspect that somehow paragraph indentation is being included; that would give a uniform additional width to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a narrow measure, you should use `\raggedright` for the titles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}[2.5in]

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}

\end{document}
```